# Cauchy seqeunces with uniformly continuous mapping is well defined

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

Let $E$ is dense in $X$ and $\{x_n\}, \{x'_n\}$ are Cauchy sequences on $E$ such that $x_n\to x$ and $x'_n\to x$ where $x\in X$. Let $f:E\to\mathbb{R}$ is uniformly continuous mapping. Prove that $$\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)=\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}f(x'_n).$$

**Proof:**
Since $f$ is uniformly continuous mapping then $\{f(x_n)\}$ and $\{f(x'_n)\}$ are Cauchy sequences in $\mathbb{R}$. Then both $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f(x_n)$ and $\lim \limits_{n\to \infty}f(x'_n)$ are exists.

It's easy to check that $d(x_n,x'_n)\to 0$ as $n\to\infty$.
Let $\varepsilon>0$ be given. Then $\exists \delta>0$ such that $d(x_n,x'_n)<\delta$ for $n\geqslant N_{\delta}$ then $d(f(x_n),f(x'_n))<\varepsilon$ by uniformly continuous of $f$.

Thus for given $\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N$ s.t. if $n\geqslant N$ then $d(f(x_n),f(x'_n))<\varepsilon$.

Is this proof correct? Please can anyone check that?

Comment: What exactly is the claim you are trying to prove? -- (To the upvoter: I think a question should at least make sense before you upvote. Thank you for observing all safety precautions).

Comment: @Thomas, Sorry please! I want to prove that $d(f(x_n),f(x'_n))\to 0.$

Comment: @Thomas, so what you think? Is it correct?

Comment: What is $E$? A finite dimensional real vectorspace?

Comment: @Thomas, $E$ is metric space.

Comment: Well, yes, the reaoning is valid, but, to be honest, a bit strange to me. Since $f$ is continous and you even know that both sequences converge to some given limit (the same in both cases) it's clear that also $f(x_n) $ and $f(x_n^\prime))$ converge to the same limit (which immediately implies your claim). For this it is sufficient to assume continuity of $f$, with the assumptions at hand uniform continuity is not needed.

Comment: (You should fix your question if you know it's incomplete)

Comment: @Thomas, What is reaoning? P.S. Sorry but English not my native.

Comment: @Thomas, I edited my post!

Comment: Typo. I wanted to write reasoning. The chain of conclusions looks valid to me.

Comment: @Thomas, Thanks a lot for checking!

Comment: @Thomas Note that the limit $x$ of the sequences need not lie in $E$, so $f$ need not be defined at $x$. In those cases, one needs the uniform continuity of $f$ to obtain the conclusion.

Comment: @RFZ Alternative argument: Consider the sequence $$y_n = \begin{cases} x_n &, n \text{ even} \\ x_n' &, n \text{ odd}. \end{cases}$$ Then $y_n \to x$, and so by uniform continuity $\bigl(f(y_n)\bigr)$ converges.

Comment: @DanielFischer, $(f(y_n))$ converges because $y_n$ is also Cauchy sequence?

Comment: Right. $(y_n)$ is convergent, hence a Cauchy sequence. Therefore $\bigl(f(y_n)\bigr)$ is a Cauchy sequence by the uniform continuity of $f$. Since $\mathbb{R}$ is complete, $\bigl(f(y_n)\bigr)$ is convergent.

Comment: @DanielFischer, Great argument as always! Everytime when I post problems and you write your ideas. They are brilliant! Thanks a lot! P.S. Sorry if I made mistake in English

Comment: @DanielFischer Correct. Note though that in the original post the nature of $E$ was not made precise. My focus was, because of this, not so much on this kind of fine points. The set $X$ in which $E$ is dense now also did not exist at that point in time...

Comment: @Thomas Didn't check the time stamps. Since that comment was made considerably later than the first comments, I thought it was made post-edit.